# Jenkins job set GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling, but hook trigger build fail

Tags: git, github, jenkins

The problem is: the build is not triggered after the code is submitted

I have a "Freestyle project" Jenkins job that has set GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling。

[job set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgI2z.png)

The system settings of Jenkins are configured with github server and the test connection is successful。

[Jenkins system setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkLuA.png)

github-> webhook also shows that the message was sent successfully

[github hook log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GT2hi.png)

But after submitting the code to github, no build was triggered. The github hook log of the job showed “FATAL: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "/usr/bin/git ls-remote -h git@github.com:yuwan1994/jenkinsdemo. git" returned status code 128:
stdout:
stderr: Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.”
[github hook log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMZtC.png)

I tried to connect to the server and executed the command "/usr/bin/git ls-remote -h git@github.com:yuwan1994/jenkinsdemo.git", but the final revised version was returned, but the final version and github hook log showed Different versions. The server display is correct

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8j9Ji.png)

Software versions:

Jenkins - 2.319.1
GitHub plugin - 1.34.1
Server System - Centos7
Server Git - 1.8.3.1

Comment: "Host key verification failed" indicates that your host (your Jenkins machine running jobs on behalf of the jenkins user) does not trust the fingerprint reported by the other machine (github.com, in this case). This is a jenkins setup issue, probably tied to `~jenkins/.ssh/known_hosts`.

Comment: @torek The machine running Jenkins has added the github website to known_hosts ·[root@iZwz9htjvskmeupewq02a4Z .ssh]# cat known_hosts 
github.com,20.205.243.166 ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNTYAAAAIbmlzd........
[root@iZwz9htjvskmeupewq02a4Z .ssh]# pwd
/root/.ssh
·

Comment: You seem to be looking at ~root/.ssh/known_hosts, not ~jenkins/.ssh/known_hosts here.

Comment: only .ssh folder has known_hosts`[root@iZwz9htjvskmeupewq02a4Z .jenkins]# find / -name known_hosts
/root/.ssh/known_hosts`@torek

Comment: Is there a Jenkins user? What home directory does the Jenkins user have?

Comment: The path of the jenkins user is /var/lib/jenkins/, It has a .ssh folder but it is empty. @torek

Comment: So, put the same stuff in *that* `.ssh/known_hosts` file (make sure it is all owned by Jenkins and has the right modes for the `.ssh` directory). That's probably the problem. (I have never set up Jenkins myself, and I know it has its own quirks, so I am not making any guarantees here.)

Comment: I copied /root/.ssh/known_hosts to /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh, and changed the permissions of the .ssh folder to 777. I restarted the Jenkins service and tried it again, but the 128 error was still reported@torek

Comment: Do you still get the "host key verification failed" message? In any case, try tracing the run to see what host key file it is using.

Comment: I found the problem. Thank you so much for your guidance.@torek

Answer (score 0):

Job->Configure->Source Code Management->Git->Repository URL need to use web url, don't use ssh url. Then choose jenkins credentials. If there is no link error, the link is normal.
[image: ssh url]

[image: http url]